# Android AppUpdateManager not initializing the auto update

Tags: java, android, google-play

I want to update my app immediately every time I publish an update. I followed the instructions from the official android documentation on how to test the auto update feature , but nothing happens. I placed some logs in order to check whether these functions initialize, but the logcat shows nothing either. Is this a problem in my syntax, or should I place these functions somewhere else? Currently, all my update code is written inside the main, starting class of the app.

On create method of the class

```
private static final int REQUEST_APP_UPDATE = 560;
private AppUpdateManager appUpdateManager;
private InstallStateUpdatedListener installStateUpdatedListener;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    appUpdateManager = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(this);


    installStateUpdatedListener = new
            InstallStateUpdatedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onStateUpdate(InstallState state) {
                    if (state.installStatus() == InstallStatus.DOWNLOADED){

                    } else if (state.installStatus() == InstallStatus.INSTALLED){
                        if (appUpdateManager != null){
                            appUpdateManager.unregisterListener(installStateUpdatedListener);
                        }

                    } else {
                        Log.i(TAG, "InstallStateUpdatedListener: state: " + state.installStatus());
                    }
                }
            };

    appUpdateManager
            .getAppUpdateInfo()
            .addOnSuccessListener(
                    appUpdateInfo -> {
                        Log.d("TAG", "here");

                        // Checks that the platform will allow the specified type of update.
                        if ((appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE)
                                && appUpdateInfo.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE))
                        {
                            // Request the update.
                            try {
                                Log.d("TAG", "here");
                                appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(
                                        appUpdateInfo,
                                        AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE,
                                        this,
                                        REQUEST_APP_UPDATE);
                            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });

    appUpdateManager.registerListener(installStateUpdatedListener);
   ...
```

On resume and on stop handling methods:

```
 @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    appUpdateManager
            .getAppUpdateInfo()
            .addOnSuccessListener(
                    appUpdateInfo -> {

                        if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability()
                                == UpdateAvailability.DEVELOPER_TRIGGERED_UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS) {
                            // If an in-app update is already running, resume the update.
                            try {
                                appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(
                                        appUpdateInfo,
                                        AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE,
                                        this,
                                        REQUEST_APP_UPDATE);
                                Log.d("TAG", "tu");
                            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
}
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (appUpdateManager != null) {
        appUpdateManager.unregisterListener(installStateUpdatedListener);
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_APP_UPDATE) {
        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Update flow failed! Result code: " + resultCode);
            // If the update is cancelled or fails,
            // you can request to start the update again.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you use internal track for publishing?

Comment: Yes, all of the updates that I tested were internal updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that I provided was working, the problem of not updating was a matter of the device itself not knowing whether an update is available. After refreshing the update list on the Play Store, the app update manager initialized the auto update window when starting the app.

Comment: Google Play Store shows there is an update available, but the inAppUpdate doesn't seem to recognize it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to move all your `AppUpdateInfo` retrieving to `onResume()` since it is more reliable entry point of an activity (for example, if Activity has came to background and then was opened again by user). OnCreate method will be called only if activity was destroyed, since that, you may not see update dialog after reopening application if it was minimized.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    appUpdateManager.getAppUpdateInfo().addOnSuccessListener( info -> {
        boolean isStalledUpdate = info.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.DEVELOPER_TRIGGERED_UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS;
        boolean isReadyForUpdate = 
            info.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE
            && info.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE;

        if (isReadyForUpdate || isStalledUpdate) {
                appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(
                    info, 
                    AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE, 
                    this, 
                    REQ_CODE
                );
        }
}
```

Sometimes app is not automatically synchronized with Play Store updates, so you need to do the following:

Make sure you have an update available manually - go to Play Store, check for updates and make sure that you have an update available for your application.
After that open your app (your activity, that calls update manager in `onResume`) and you will see immediate update dialog.

Also, one tip for you - make your Activity implement InstallStateUpdateListener and override method `onStateUpdate` like this to handle different events.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    // All previous logic 
    // If update is available or was stalled call this
    appUpdateManager.registerListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onStateUpdate(InstallState state) {
    if (state == null) return;
    switch (state.installStatus()) {
        case InstallStatus.INSTALLED: 
            appUpdateManager.unregisterListener(this)
            return;
        case InstallStatus.FAILED:
            appUpdateManager.unregisterListener(this)
            return;
        case InstallStatus.CANCELED:
            appUpdateManager.unregisterListener(this)
            return;
        default:
            // provide your own logic
            return;
    }
}
```

This will help you to avoid calling separate instance of listener in activity lifecycle methods.

Comment: I moved the code to the onResume, updated the project in the google play console, manually searched for updates on my device, tested it, and it still doesn't seem to work, nothing happens.

Comment: @Xarxes you should ensure that you are on internal track and the update is available in play store. Do you see message like this one on the screenshot? https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZ142.jpg

Comment: my update is availible to download in play store, I don't update it, after checking whether the update is possible I head straight to my app, but nothing happens. I do have the message warning me about the internal testing.

Comment: @Xarxes it is pretty interesting. Did you log your app update info's onSuccessListener? Does the code under the condition of update availability gets called?

Comment: My logs:
AppUpdateService : requestUpdateInfo("app name")
AppUpdateService : Initiate binding to the service.
AppUpdateListenerRegistry : registerListener
AppUpdateService : requestUpdateInfo(com.sunfamily.bonus)
AppUpdateListenerRegistry : registerListener
AppUpdateService : Waiting to bind to the service.
 AppUpdateService : ServiceConnectionImpl.onServiceConnected(ComponentInfo{com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.installservice.DevTriggeredUpdateService})
 AppUpdateService : linkToDeath
OnRequestInstallCallback : onRequestInfo
AppUpdateService : Unbind from service.

Comment: @Xarxes can you add something like `Log.d("TAG", info.toString())` in onSuccessListener and check the logs?

Comment: The log doesn't appear in the logcat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220359/discussion-between-steyrix-and-xarxes).